# can not split large .txt file into train, test and validation parts for deep text corrector

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science

I have a single large .txt file and I want to split it into train, test and validation set. below are the lines of code where I want to use those flies. I am not getting any intuition about how to do it.

```
python correct_text.py --train_path 
                        /movie_dialog_train.txt \
                       --val_path /movie_dialog_val.txt \
                       --config DefaultMovieDialogConfig \
                       --data_reader_type MovieDialogReader \
                       --model_path /movie_dialog_model
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the large file into a Pandas DataFrame(say, *df*) using `pd.from_csv()` method 
After this, you can split the dataframe into Train(*df_train*) and Test(*df_val*)

Now, you can use the `pd.to_csv()` two times and pass the filenames as a function parameter to generate text files of *movie_dialog_train.txt* and *movie_dialog_val.txt*

You can create a small Python script just for this and run it, so that your train and validation files are present before you actually run the code.

Comment: thanks for replying Aditya. problem is that it is a text file that contains movies dialog. its not in CSV. Are you saying that i have to convert this text file to CSV before splitting it. i do not think that a good approach. please let me know what you think about it.

Comment: No, in Pandas the `to_csv` method handles text data as well, you just don't have to specify anything for the parameter `\sep=`